# curl error 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining

Tags: bash, curl

**Setup**

I'm Using curl in the following bash script to push a JSON file to a REST API running in tomcat sitting behind nginx.

```
while IFS= read -d '' -r file; do
base=$(basename "$file")
datetime=$(find $file -maxdepth 0 -printf "%TY/%Tm/%Td %TH:%TM:%.2TS")
curl -vX POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" \
  -d @"$file" -u vangeeij:eian12 \
  "http://192.168.105.10/homeaccess/services/aCStats/uploadData?username=vangeeij&filename=$base&datetime=$datetime"
#sudo mv "$file" /home/vangeeij/acserver/resultsOld
done < <(sudo find . -type f -print0)
```

**Problem**

When running this script I get a http 400 response with curl error:

```
curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
```

**What I have tried**

I have found 2 things.  First running the same URL and body through Postman yields a successful POST.

I found that this error goes away when the last parameter is removed from the URL `&datetime=$datetime`

I have also found a few connections between this error and setting a curl option something like

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));
```

But I'm not sure where/how to set this exactly when using curl in a simple bash script

**Question**

What do I need to change in my curl command to get rid of the error and still be able to use all parameters?

**UPDATE**

Starting a new question, as further investigation has lead me to a better understanding of the problem.

[New Question Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42743645/curl-post-json-file-to-rest-api-while-also-using-data-urlencode-to-encode-quer)

The error has to do with the fact that the parameter datetime= ends up with text in it that needs to be URL encoded.

*This was confirmed by replacing the variable with 2017%2F03%2F01%2008%3A50%3A56*

and it worked.

So now the problem is, that I can't get --data-urlencode datetime=$datetime to work.  It seems this just gets appended to the JSON data or something.

Comment: I would try to remove the '\n' in this line. datetime=$(find $file -maxdepth 0 -printf "%TY/%Tm/%Td %TH:%TM:%.2TS\n"). You can also add -d "username=vangeeij&filename=$base&datetime=$datetime" and remove it from the URL, because curl merge multiple -d's

Comment: I didn't notice the \n there.. I removed that... but the error still exists.   Updating the above to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is being generated by the fact that the datetime= paramater is being passed in with non encoded non URL friendly characters... (eg. space).

The fix to this would be to find a way to convert the $datetime to a URLEncoded String.

eg. convert:

```
2017/03/01 08:50:56
```

TO

```
2017%2F03%2F01%2008%3A50%3A56
```

See the following discussion for one method to accomplish this.

[Post JSON data to Rest with URLEncoded query paramaters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42743645/curl-post-json-file-to-rest-api-while-also-using-data-urlencode-to-encode-quer)